# Proteger rutas en ReactJS

Tags: javascript, firebase, reactjs

He creado un sistema de registro usando **Firebase Auth** y quiero proteger las rutas para que solo puedan ser accesibles a usuarios *«loggeados»*.

He dividido mi proyecto en los componentes de *«loggeo»* y registro y mi archivo de *«routes»* (donde especifico mis rutas y autentico y/o registro usuarios).

Este es mi archivo **Signin** donde envío todos los datos recolectados en el formulario a mi archivo *routes* por medio de `props`.

```
export default class FormularioSignin extends Component {

  EmailRef = React.createRef();
  PassRef = React.createRef();

  signinPost = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    const postSignin = {
      email: this.EmailRef.current.value,
      pass: this.PassRef.current.value
    };
    console.log(postSignin)

    this.props.signinPost(postSignin)
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="background">
        <div className="signin-card">
          <div className="row">
            <form className="col s12" onSubmit={this.signinPost}>
              <div className="row center">
                <Avatar />
                <div className="input-field col s12">
                  <input type="text" ref={this.EmailRef} id="email" className="validate" />
                  <label htmlFor="email">Email</label>
                </div>
                <div className="input-field col s12">
                  <input ref={this.PassRef} type="password" id="password" className="validate" />
                  <label htmlFor="password">Password</label>
                </div>
                <label>
                  <input type="checkbox" />
                  <span>Mantener sesion iniciada</span>
                </label>
              </div>
              <div className="btn-div center">
                <button type="submit" className="waves-effect waves-light btn btn-log">Signin</button>
                <p>
                  No account?<Link to="/Signup"> Create One!!</Link>
                </p>
              </div>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

En mi archivo de *«routes»* recibo los datos enviados desde los formularios y registro los usuarios en **Firebase**.

```
const firebaseApp = firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
console.log(firebaseApp);

export default class Router extends Component {
  state = {
    prevLocation: null,
    Username: null,
    loggedIn: false
  };


  signupPost = postSignup => {
    console.log(postSignup);
    const name = postSignup.username;
    const mail = postSignup.email;
    const pass = postSignup.password;

    firebase
      .auth()
      .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(mail, pass)

      .then(user => {
        console.log("registrado", user);
        Swal.fire({
          icon: "success",
          title: "Usuario Registrado",
          text: name
        });



        User.updateProfile({
          displayName: name,
          photoURL: "https://example.com/jane-q-user/profile.jpg"
        });
        this.setState({
          Username: name,
          loggedIn: true
        });
        localStorage.setItem("User", JSON.stringify(this.state));


      })

      .catch(error => {
        var errorMessage = error.message;
        Swal.fire({
          icon: "error",
          title: "Oops...",
          text: errorMessage
        });
      });
  };

  signinPost = postSignin => {
    firebase
      .auth()
      .signInWithEmailAndPassword(postSignin.email, postSignin.pass)

      .then(user => {
        console.log("loggeado", user);
        Swal.fire({
          icon: "success",
          title: "Bienvenido"
        });
        let userr = firebase.auth().currentUser;
        let namee;
        if (userr != null) {
          namee = userr.displayName;
          this.setState({
            Username: namee,
            loggedIn: true
          });
        }
      })

      .catch(error => {
        var errorMessage = error.message;
        Swal.fire({
          icon: "error",
          title: "Oops...",
          text: errorMessage
        });
      });
    const resul = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("User"));
    const na = resul.Username;
    console.log(na);
  };

  render() {

    return (
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
          <ProtectedRoute
            exact
            path="/dashboard"
            component={Dashboard}
          />
          <Route
            exact
            path="/signin"
            render={() => {
              return <FormularioSignin signinPost={this.signinPost} />;
            }}
          />
          <Route
            exact
            path="/signup"
            render={() => {
              return <FormularioSignup signupPost={this.signupPost} />;
            }}
          />
        </Switch>
      </BrowserRouter>
    );
  }
}
```

Ahora, el problema es que no sé cómo proteger mi *«ruta /dashboard»* para que solo pueda acceder un usuario registrado.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En un proyecto me toco meter mano a algo como lo que necesitas y estaba de esta manera:

```
<BrowserRouter>
  <Switch>
    <Route path="/signin" exact component={Auth} />
    <PrivateRoute path="/dashboard" auth={auth} component={Dashboard} />
  </Switch>
</BrowserRouter>
```

En otro archivo se crea otro el componente PrivateRoute
    const PrivateRoute = (props) => {
      const {isAuthenticated } = props.path

```
  if (isAuthenticated) {
    return <Route {...props} /> // haciendo esto se pasa el prop `path`, `auth` y `component`
  }

  return <Redirect to="/signin" />
}
```

Si miras es una simple validacion, si esta autenticado o tiene una sesion activa o la validacion quieras, te manda a esa ruta y si no te regresa al componente que quieras, en el ejemplo a la ruta "/signing". Es algo sencillo y simple y funciona, es una opcion, si alguien tiene una mejor estaria genial ver ese approach.